# bash: zpool: command not found

Tags: bash, debian, zfs, command-not-found

After a lot of hassle, I finally managed to install the newest spl-dkms and zfs-dkms on my Raspbian. Sadly I still can neither use the `zpool` nor the `zfs` command to list or change any ZFS pools.
Is there any additional package I need?

Because on many other distros installing *zfs-dkms* was enough for *zpool* and *zfs* to be available.

Comment: did you check in /sbin ? and its there in your PATH ?

Comment: I don't see anything related to `zpool` or `zfs` in /sbin...

Comment: I suggest you follow the guide at: http://www.zfsonlinux.org Specifically, if you're using raspbian you will probably want this guide (referenced from above): https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Debian

Comment: Try `sudo find / -name 'zpool'` to find it.

Comment: You can see which files were installed by a specific package using `dpkg -L <packagename>`, for example `dpkg -L zfs-dkms`. This can be done as an ordinary user. Note: This does not include any files created separately from or subsequently after the package installation proper.

Comment: What are those commands supposed to output? The first one didn't find anythinf, the second one printed the whole list of installed things and `grep zpool` only showed me `zpool_prop.c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, there were some missing dependencies. So I had to re-install the current spl and zfs version, then manually download two packages from https://packages.debian.org/ :

`libnvpair1linux_0.6.5.9-5_armhf.deb` and `libuutil1linux_0.6.5.9-5_armhf.deb`